# Locus problem, circle

Tags: circles, locus

A variable line moves in such way that the product of the perpendiculars form $(a,0)$ and $(0,0)$ is equal to $k^2$.The locus of the foot of the perpendicular from $(0,0)$ upon the variable line is a circle, the square of whose radius is? (Given : $|a| < 2|k|$)

Comment: The second constraint of the locus is too strong.

Comment: Meaning? I'm sure that the question is right, I've typed it verbatim.

Comment: Welcome to Math StackExchange. You are sure of the question, but are you sure you have worked on it ? Could you show us your attempts ? Where are you blocked ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I solved it. Let the variable line be $xx_1+yy_1=x_1^2 + y_1^2$. By length of perpendicular you get $ |x_1^2 + y_1^2-a x_1| = k^2 \implies r^2 = a^2+k/4$. Thanks for nothing!

Comment: My bad, I tecognize my error.

Comment: "I've typed it verbatim."  Likely "form" should have been "from", but typing problems verbatim means you omitted the *context* in which the problem came to your attention.  I'm happy you were able to solve it.  Voting to close because without context, it's unlikely to help future Readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $O=(0,0)$, $A=(a,0)$, $B=(X,Y)$ be the foot for $O$ and $C$ be the foot for $A$.

The equation of the dynamic line is 
$$\fbox{$X x+Y y = X^2+Y^2$}$$

Now,

\begin{align}
  OB \times AC &= k^2 \\
  \left|
    \frac{-X^2-Y^2}{\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}}
    \times
    \frac{aX-X^2-Y^2}{\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}}
  \right| &= k^2 \\
  X^2+Y^2-aX &= \pm k^2 \\
  \left( X-\frac{a}{2} \right)^2+Y^2 &= \frac{a^2}{4} \pm k^2
\end{align}

Therefore,

$$\fbox{$r = \sqrt{\frac{a^2}{4} \pm k^2}$}$$

> **I'd like to show the geometrical interpretation here.**

- Interestingly, $C$ also falls on the circle.
- For $X^2+Y^2-aX = k^2$ where $a,k\ne 0$

  [image]

  Considering $OA$ as hypotenuse,

  $$(AC-OB)^2+BC^2=a^2$$

  Considering diameter $BB'$ or $CC'$ as hypotenuse,

  $$(AC+OB)^2+BC^2=4r^2$$

  Eliminating $BC$ gives $$\fbox{$AC\times OB =r^2-\frac{a^2}{4}$}$$
- For $X^2+Y^2-aX = -k^2$ where $a^2>4k^2$

  [image]

  Considering $OA$ as hypotenuse,

  $$(AC+OB)^2+BC^2=a^2$$

  Considering diameter $BB'$ or $CC'$ as hypotenuse,

  $$(AC-OB)^2+BC^2=4r^2$$

  Eliminating $BC$ gives $$\fbox{$AC\times OB =\frac{a^2}{4}-r^2$}$$

Comment: Just what I was looking for thanks! PS: $\fbox{$r = \sqrt{\frac{a^2}{4} + k^2}$}$  as $|a| < |2k|$, not $\pm$.

Comment: [+1] Very thorough answer.